# Preimage set of complex polynomial is connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f(z) \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ with deg$(f) \geq 1$. Then $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)| > 1\}$ is connected.

I know that $f(z)$ is holomorphic, so continuous on $\mathbb{C}.$ I dont think that preimage of connected set under continuous map is always connected.

Right now I just know that $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |f(z)| > 1\}$ is open since it is exactly the set $|f|^{-1}((1,\infty)).$

Answer (score 3):

Since the given set contains the exterior of a large circle $C$, there is certainly a connected component that contains $\infty$, which also contains the exterior of $C$.

Suppose the statement is not true. Then there will be another connected component $D$, which is inside $C$. Since $\lvert f\rvert$ is continuous $D$ is a compact domain. Apply the maximum modulus principle to $f$ in $D$: $\lvert f\rvert$ takes on its maximum on the boundary of $D$, but $\lvert f\rvert \geq 1$ on the interior of $D$ by the definition of $D$, so $D$ must be constant, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Exterior ? Do you mean it is the complement of interior points of $C$ ? It is in topology sense ? (I dont know the definition of exterior points, but I guess you mean outside of the interior ?)

Comment: When you speak of $\infty$, do you mean the extended complex plane ? (I think this problem is proved in $\mathbb{C}$, not in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$)

Comment: I mean a set of the form $\{ z : z>R \}$. This is because $\lim_{z \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert = \infty$ for polynomials.

Comment: why $|f| \geq 1$ on the interios of $D$ ?

Comment: $D$ is a connected component of the set on which $|f| > 1$, so *a fortiori* $|f|>1$ on the $\text{int }{D} \subseteq D$.